# how to add a img tag to an anchor tag in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add an image to my anchor tag in jquery,but the image seems to be broken.

what i tried/tested:

- the path of the image is correct
- did a test and added it into html and the image shows.

  `<div><img src="~/ClientData/10000/Styles/images/menu.png"/></div>` // just a test.image works in html

i am trying to add it to the following

```
 $('#navbar-collapse-menu li:eq(0)').after('<li  style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#fcd18b 0,#faa61d 100%)"><a id="Menu" href="http://test.aspx"><img src="~/ClientData/10000/Styles/images/menu.png"/>Menu</a></li>'); // the image gets broken in here.
```

is there a different way i can add the image to the above code?

Comment: is `~/ClientData/10000/Styles/images/menu.png` your absolute path on your server side ?

Comment: That is the correct path,because when i add it to html,as mentioned above it works

Comment: @StéphaneAmmar yep.

Comment: when you run this code `li` is actually added? Are you sure? What error you got inside browser console? check and tell.

Comment: So, your client can't access it, and this is why you have a broken image.

Comment: @AlivetoDie yep it works. it can find the image,thats why its broken,i wanted to know is there another way to add it in?

Comment: @StéphaneAmmar yes thats correct

Comment: you need to provide full url there as  you said  `~/ClientData/10000/Styles/images/menu.png` is your absolute path on your server side

Comment: I am assuming that `ClientData` is your project root directory. Did you tried to provide path like this; `<img src="/10000/Styles/images/menu.png"/>` it is absolute path to file with in your root directory. You can change it according to your projects root directory.

Comment: By using `~/ClientData...` is it safe to assume that you're also using ASP.Net / MVC?   If so, the `~` is translated by the server to your application path and won't be available client-side.  There's an easy work around which I can provide if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can only put block-level elements inside anchor elements with HTML5 and browser support is still a bit iffy on it. IE7 obviously does not support this.

You can take reference of following code and put it as your need into your jquery code above. But be sure that you jquery code is error free.

```
<div>                      
   <a title="X" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
      <img src="Images/X.png"/> 
   </a>  
</div>
```

Check w3shcool Example at [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_image_link).